# combining two arrays using other methods other than array_splice

Tags: php

So I have two sets of arrays:

```
$a = [
    [
      'position' => 0,
      'color'    => 'violet'
    ],
    [
      'position' => 2,
      'color'    => 'red'
    ],
    [
      'position' => 5,
      'color'    => 'green'
    ],
];

$b = [
    [
      'color' => 'yellow'
    ],
    [
      'color' => 'orange'
    ],
    [
      'color' => 'pink'
    ],
    [
      'color' => 'blue'
    ],
];
```

And what I want to display from this is something like this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "violet"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "yellow"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "orange"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "pink"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
}
```

I'm currently using `array_splice` and it does work but it is very slow whenever there's a lot of data.
`array_splice` method:

```
foreach($a as $val) {
    array_splice($b, (int) $val['position'], 0, [['color' => $val['color']]]);
}
```

So what I want to ask is, is there like a PHP function for this or any other ways just to make it fast?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses $a to get a "start" with array_column to get `[pos => color]`.

Then I loop this array to see if there is a missing key, if there is a missing key add one item from $b, else reformat the array from `[post => color]` to `[['color' => color]]`

```
$pos = array_column($a, "color", "position");

$count = count($pos) + count($b);

for($i=0; $i<$count-1; $i++){
    if(!isset($pos[$i])){
        $pos[$i] = array_splice($b, 0, 1);
    }else{
        $pos[$i] = [$pos[$i]];
    }
}
ksort($pos);

var_dump($pos);
```

Same code but without array_splice.
Using a counter to know what item to pick from $b.

```
$pos = array_column($a, "color", "position");

$count = count($pos) + count($b);
$j = 0;

for($i=0; $i<$count-1; $i++){
    if(!isset($pos[$i])){
        $pos[$i] = $b[$j];
        $j++;
    }else{
        $pos[$i] = [$pos[$i]];
    }
}
ksort($pos);

var_dump($pos);
```

https://3v4l.org/3uPM3

But this requires $b to be indexed.

Comment: May be instead of `$b[$j]`, `array_shift` would work.

Comment: True, but that will also manipulate `$b`. I used the counter since that does no changes to the array. Counting is probably faster than manipulating an array(?). But I'm not so sure mine is better than your improved version in performance. I'm quite sure Nigel's is the fastest. @SougataBose

Comment: Yes. May be a copy then. That would remove the use of an extra var and increments.

Answer (score 1):

This loops through the two arrays together, check the number of items output against the position of the insert of `$a`.  If this matches, it adds the value before adding the value in `$b`.  I use `?? $index + 1` in the test so that if you have run out of elements in `$a`, this will always check against `$index + 1` which will always fail.

Note that it uses the output position and not the index of `$b` (which was my initial mistake)...

```
$acurrent = 0;
$output = [];
$outputCount = 0;
foreach ( $b as $bStart )   {
    if ( $outputCount == ($a[$acurrent]['position'] ?? $index + 1) )   {
        $output[] = ['color' => $a[$acurrent]['color']];
        $outputCount++;
        $acurrent++;
    }
    $output[] = $bStart;
    $outputCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also help -

```
$limit = count($a) + count($b); // get the total number of elements to loop
$new = [];
// Extract positions from first array for checks
$positions = array_column($a, 'color', 'position');
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $new[]['color'] = isset($positions[$i]) ? $positions[$i] : array_shift($b)['color'];
}
```

Comment: Especially on each iteration... Maybe if you at least put array_column outside

Comment: @Andreas, yours better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
foreach ($a as &$col) {
    $b[] = array('color' => $col['color']);
}

print_r($b);
```

https://paiza.io/projects/RlMs11FHx1DpA6N43Da8dg